# Stream file to server from Cordova app

Tags: cordova, amazon-s3, stream

I have cordova app where the user must be able to select an image off their phone and upload it to AWS S3. I'm using [cordova-plugin-camera](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera) and the S3 SDK for this. I have code that works fine (see below), but requires the entire image to be pulled into memory inside a base64 encoded string (per [Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#cameradestinationtype--enum)) and then again into a `Buffer`.

I'd prefer to have this streamed off the phone's hard drive to mitigate potential memory issues. The [cordova-plugin-camera](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#module_Camera.EncodingType) website even has a warning about this:

> /**  * Warning: Using DATA_URL is not recommended! The DATA_URL
>   destination  * type is very memory intensive, even with a low quality
>   setting. Using it  * can result in out of memory errors and
>   application crashes. Use FILE_URI  * or NATIVE_URI instead.  */

So is there any way to stream the photo straight from the disk up to S3 using `FILE_URI` or `NATIVE_URI` or any other technique?

Here's my current code:

```
doTheThing() {
    let options = {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPG
    };

    navigator.camera.getPicture(imgData => {
       this.uploadToS3(imgData);
    }, options);


    uploadToS3(data) {
        let AWS = require('aws-sdk');

        AWS.config = new AWS.Config();
        AWS.config.accessKeyId = 'noway';
        AWS.config.secretAccessKey = 'jose';
        AWS.config.region = 'us-east-2';

        let s3 = new AWS.S3();
        let uploadParams = { Bucket: 'iamkule/f1/f2', Key: '', Body: new Buffer(data, 'base64') };
        uploadParams.Key = 'myfile.jpg';

        s3.upload(uploadParams, function (err, data) {
           if (data) {
              console.log('yay!');
           }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: did you looked at file upload plugin?

Comment: @Gandhi can I get a url for that? Do you mean cordova-plugin-file-transfer (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer)?

Comment: file transfer plugin is what I es referring. There is a upload function which u can try in that

Comment: jus check out the link - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations and see if it helps

Comment: any clue on this?

Comment: @Gandhi looks like it could work. Thanks for the pointer. If you want to put together a working example, there's like 50 points in it for you. :)

Comment: unfortunately I don't have setup to test even if make code changes. The sample in git  should work as is for download which u can just extend

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started. Please forgive my pseudo code. Feel free to edit it as needed.

Device saves image to disk:

```
function takePicture(urlCallback){
    let options = {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,// <--
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPG
    };
    navigator.camera.getPicture(urlCallback, onFail, options);  
    function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }
}
```

Get the image from disk as a blob:

```
function getImageAsBlob(url, blobCallback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open( "GET", url, true );
    xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    xhr.onload = function( ev ) {
        // Obtain a blob: URL for the image data.
        var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array( this.response );
        var blob = new Blob( [ arrayBufferView ], { type: "image/jpeg" } );
        blobCallback(blob);
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

Upload the blob to S3:

```
function uploadToS3(blob, callback) {
    let AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    AWS.config = new AWS.Config();
    AWS.config.accessKeyId = 'noway';
    AWS.config.secretAccessKey = 'jose';
    AWS.config.region = 'us-east-2';
    let s3 = new AWS.S3();
    let options = { Bucket: 'iamkule/f1/f2', Key: 'myfile.jpg', Body: blob };// <--
    s3.upload(options, callback);
}
```

Putting it all together:

```
takePicture(function(url){
    getImageAsBlob(url, function(blob){
        uploadToS3(blob, function (err, data) {
            if (data) console.log('yay!');
        });
    });
});
```

S3 info came from [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property). Photo capture info came from [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.0.0/cordova/camera/camera.getPicture.html).
 Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm having trouble understanding what's going on in the `getImageAsBlob()` function. The `url` parameter should be the path to the image file on the phone, but you're not doing anything with it. Instead you're downloading an image from http://fiddle.jshell.cnet? Not sure I get that.

Comment: I've fixed the bug. The code was not end to end tested, but I tested what I could before posting. The solution may require additional updates, but should get you started.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know you could use XMLHttpRequest to "GET" something from the file system. And while I appreciate the effort, this doesn't really solve the core problem because it doesn't stream the file off disk up to S3. You're still holding the entire file in memory. You do eliminate the base 64 byte string though, which is nice.

Comment: You have to have permissions set to access the device's directory. The reason I considered this the right solution is the S3 api doesn't provide a file writer that supports self managed chunking or a streaming  implementation. Without rewriting the s3 sdk code and taking ownership of the implementation you're stuck with whole file processing. The blob will be at least 25% smaller than the base64 and requires no processing. It may be that the base64 implementation is actually 160% larger (2.6X) than the implementation I provided if it loads both the binary prior to processing it into base64.

Comment: That's doesn't mention the fact that if you're going to achieve any savings within the s3 sdk functions it is likely to be achieved using binary. The best thing you can do is run each a few times and profile each.